# any specific command to just list the user processes in linux?

Tags: linux

Is there a command/way to just display the list of user processes in linux ? I have tried ps -ef, top etc all these seem to be listing kernel processes as well. Basically, i am trying to verify the wdt of each user process in a linux based device.

Comment: Read `man ps` or `man top`, both have options to restrict output based on username.

Comment: @LevLevitsky I know how to restrict output based on username. My question is more about a command to just list out the processes in user space. Note that the processes in user space and in kernel space can still be root, so restricting output based on username is not gonna help my case.

Comment: For example, 2 root       0:00 [kthreadd] is in kernel space and 1625 root       0:00 httpd is in user space... how do I determine which one runs on user process just by the user name?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. ps itself does not have this option. Just filter everything with grep

```
ps au | grep ^username
```